# After successful callback from facebook socialite, I get redirected to the login page

Tags: php, laravel-5.7, laravel-socialite

I'm trying to setup 'Login with facebook' using laravel socialite. When I try to login, it gets a successful callback from the facebook, I'm storing the data fetched into the database and try to redirect to home page. While doing so, I am redirected back to the login page and never reaching the homepage.

Here is my code-
**AuthController.php**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;
use Socialite;
use App\User;

[.. // class defination and home redirect variable

public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
   return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
  $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
  // dd($user);
  $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);
  Auth::login($authUser, true);
  return redirect($this->redirectTo);
}

public function findOrCreateUser($user, $provider)
{
   $authUser = User::where('id', $user->id)->first();
   if ($authUser) {
       return $authUser;
}
   return User::create([
       'name'     => $user->name,
       'email'    => $user->email,
       // 'avatar'    => $user->avatar,
       'provider' => $provider,
       'id' => $user->id
  ]);
}
..]
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('auth/{provider}', 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', 'Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

**.env file**

```
CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost/xampp/tccdev/public/auth/facebook/callback
```

Do let me know if you want some other codes.

Comment: My guess (without knowing much about Laravel) is, that the value of `$this->redirectTo` doesn't have the proper value at this point?

Comment: It has been set. I have not shown here in the code.
`protected $redirectTo = '/home';`

Answer (score 0):

You should directly use the redirect with the route like:

```
return redirect(route("routeNameGoesHere"));
```

Or you can use show the user your desired view like:

```
return view("viewNameGoesHere");
```